# Python - Create a dictionary from two lists with list name as key and list elements as values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a complete newbie to python and coding as well.

I have 2 lists. `Name=['John','Ravi','Sam']` and `Age=[23,45,34]`. How do i create a dictionary with Name and Age as keys and dictionary values from lists' elements. Resulting dictionary would look like

```
d={'Name':['John','Ravi','Sam'],'Age':[23,45,34])
```

I tried zip and fromkeys, but that doesn't work. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `d = {'Name': Name, 'Age': Age}`

Comment: it's not every interesting to have such a dictionary. Better zip both lists to create a 1 to 1 dict name=>age: `d = dict(zip(Name,Age))`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this dynamically, because there's no way to get from a value (lists in your case) to the names (note the plural) that refer to it.

Like Aran-Fey already commented, you must hardcode the keys via

```
d = {'Name': Name, 'Age': Age}
```

If the names in `Name` and the ages in `Age` correspond, why don't you create a direct mapping?

```
>>> name_to_age = dict(zip(Name, Age))
>>> name_to_age
{'John': 23, 'Ravi': 45, 'Sam': 34}
>>> name_to_age['Ravi']
45
```